# Common table expression and pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Iam trying on a sql query but i cant do something.I want to do paging by using row_number in this query but i cant figure out what will i have to put "row_number between" statement.Any help is appreciated.

```
  WITH cte_ana
     AS (SELECT movie_id,
                id,
                tag_id
         FROM   dt_movieTag)
SELECT Kayit.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY movie_id) as RowNum
FROM   cte_ana PIVOT(MAX(id) FOR tag_id IN ([3], [5], [9]))AS Kayit
where  Kayit.[3] is not null
       and kayit.[5] is not null
       and kayit.[9] is not null
order  by movie_id
```

For example i want to select only few data from this query by this (where RowNum between 0 and 25 )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `row_number` in the `where` clause so need to nest CTEs. (Obviously you could just use `TOP (25)` instead if you want the **first** 25 rows).

```
WITH cte_ana
     AS (SELECT movie_id,
                id,
                tag_id
         FROM   dt_movieTag),
cte2 AS
(         
SELECT Kayit.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY movie_id) as RowNum
FROM   cte_ana PIVOT(MAX(id) FOR tag_id IN ([3], [5], [9]))AS Kayit
where  Kayit.[3] is not null
       and kayit.[5] is not null
       and kayit.[9] is not null
)
SELECT *
FROM   cte2
WHERE RowNum <= 25      
order  by movie_id
```